# Bit plane slicing in python

Tags: python, opencv, image-compression

I recently came across a technique called bit-plane slicing for image 
compression in a book "Digital image processing" by gonzalez and woods . They 
just presented the theory and i wanted to implement it . So ,my code just creates images out of 8th bit and 7th bit plane seperately and saves them . I 
just wanted to make sure that the output is really correct . please check these code and make it more efficient or give your own version.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

#create a image array
img = cv2.imread("WIN_20170511_13_06_18_Pro.jpg",cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
row ,col = img.shape
#convert each interger pixel value of given image to a bit pixel value of 8-
 #bits
def intToBitArray(img) :
    list = []

    for i in range(row):
        for j in range(col):
             list.append (np.binary_repr( img[i][j] ,width=8  ) )

    return list #the binary_repr() fucntion returns binary values but in 
                #string 
                #, not integer, which has it's own perk as you will notice   

 #as variable name says ,it's list of pixel values in binary , but in 1 
 #dimension
imgIn1D = intToBitArray(img)
#reshaping above 1D array to a matrix aka image
imgIn2D = np.reshape(imgIn1D , (360,640) )
def bitplane(bitImgVal , img1D ):

'''
this function extracts the specific bit out of each binary pixel values of 
the matrix
for example , if bitImgVal = 3 , then , third bit of each pixel is extracted

:param bitImgVal: specifies the position of bit to be extracted
:param img1D: image which is to be compressed
:return: now returns 1 dimensional list of bits
'''
    bitList = [  int(   i[bitImgVal]  )    for i in img1D]

    return bitList
#i don't know why but the multiplication factor is : 2^(n-1) where n is the 
bit number
#example, if binary pixel value is 11001010 and n = 3 , factor = 2^(3-1)
#image represented by 8th bit plane
eightbitimg = np.array( bitplane(0, imgIn1D ) ) * 128

#image represented by 7th bit plane
sevenbitimg = np.array( bitplane(1,imgIn1D) ) * 64

#bitplane of 8th and 7th bit
combine = eightbitimg + sevenbitimg
comb = np.reshape(combine,(row,col))

#save combined plane image
cv2.imwrite("comb.jpeg",comb)

#save eight bit plane
eightbitimg = np.reshape(eightbitimg,(row,col))
cv2.imwrite("8bitvalue.jpg" , eightbitimg )

#save eight bit plane
sevenbitimg = np.reshape(sevenbitimg,(row,col))
cv2.imwrite("7bitvalue.jpg",sevenbitimg)

#grayscale version of original image
gray = cv2.imread("WIN_20170511_13_06_18_Pro.jpg",cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
cv2.imwrite("gray.jpeg",gray)
```

the images are as :
eigth BIt image:

[image]

seventh bit image

[image]

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('inputs/Lenna-220px.png', 0) 

out = []

for k in range(0, 7):
    # create an image for each k bit plane
    plane = np.full((img.shape[0], img.shape[1]), 2 ** k, np.uint8)
    # execute bitwise and operation
    res = cv2.bitwise_and(plane, img)
    # multiply ones (bit plane sliced) with 255 just for better visualization
    x = res * 255
    # append to the output list
    out.append(x)

cv2.imshow("bit plane", np.hstack(out))
cv2.waitKey()
```

Answer (score 0):

When we talk about Bit-Plane Slicing, we means to get each bit-plane eg. 0, 1 or more and then convert it to int and then try to show that bit plane. Then we will be able to see the impact of each Bit-Plane in image. My code do this as follow:

```
def getPlane(planeId, binary_image):
    switcher = {
        7:[int(b[0] + '0'*7) for b in binary_image],
        6:[int( '0' + b[1] + '0'*6) for b in binary_image],
        5:[int( '0'*2 + b[2] + '0'*5) for b in binary_image],
        4:[int( '0'*3 + b[3] + '0'*4) for b in binary_image],
        3:[int( '0'*4 + b[4] + '0'*3) for b in binary_image],
        2:[int( '0'*5 + b[5] + '0'*2) for b in binary_image],
        1:[int( '0'*6 + b[6] + '0') for b in binary_image],
        0:[int( '0'*7 + b[7]) for b in binary_image]
    }
    return switcher.get(planeId, None)

# image size is (225, 225)
bit_planes = []
c = 0
while( c < 225*225):
    bit_planes.append (np.binary_repr( img[c][0] ,width=8  ) )
    c  = c + 1
c = 0
while(c < 8):
    cv.imwrite('Bit_Plane\plane'+str(c)+ '.jpg', np.array(getPlane(c, bit_planes)).reshape(225, 225))
    c = c + 1
```

[image: 5th Bit-Plane][image: 7th Bit-Plane]